# Grid in Angular without $scope

Tags: angularjs, grid, ng-grid

Has anyone implemented a grid control in AngularJS using the `controller as` syntax? I was working with `ng-grid` but am finding out it heavily relies on us injecting `$scope` into all of our controllers.

Here is one example of it not performing properly: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kyf6eZFrDnAtwaKJiC0K?p=preview

Even though there are only 5 items in the list, the pager at the bottom allows you to go forward as many pages as you want. This is because the `totalServerItems` property not being set correctly.

There are a slew of other oddities, such as events not firing, data array lengths not being set and just overall not working real well.

Has anyone worked with any grids in AngularJS that support the `controller as` syntax?

Link to `controller as` syntax: [Reference](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

Answer (score 1):

With two little changes at least your pager does stop:

```
// main.js

(function() {

  angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

  function MyCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    vm.totalServerItems = vm.myData.length;
    vm.gridOptions = { 
      data: "mc.myData",
      enablePaging: true,
      totalServerItems: 'mc.totalServerItems',
      showFooter: true
    };
  }

})();
```

Changes:

```
vm.totalServerItems = vm.myData.length;
```

and

```
totalServerItems: 'mc.totalServerItems',
```

Does that help?

Comment: Although it can be done like this I definitely prefer the $scope solution. Everybody knows it and there is no hustle. And perhaps even if it is possible to have different names for "the scope" (John Papa: "The name vm here in the JavaScript does not have to match what is used in the View. ") I would call the two (vm and mc) identically, if I would use that approach. But that is of course just a personal preference.

Comment: That does help, thanks. I actually prefer the non-$scope solution, and it just seems odd to me that no grid solution I have found so far really supports it. I guess I can do what I need to do using the method you provided above, but it just makes the code messier.